# using arrays instead of arrayLists

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program that reads input number of products from user and then asks from user the name of product and the product's price in a loop. It then uses an Array (not arrayList) to store them.

I have written a class for the products named products (I can get rid of the class its just to make it easier)

```
public class Products {
    String ProductName;
    double ProductPrice;

    public Products(String a , double b) {
        setProductName(a);
        setProductPrice(b);         
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return ProductName;
    }

    public double getProductPrice() {
        return ProductPrice;
    }

    public void setProductName(String a) {
        ProductName = a;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(double b) {
        ProductPrice = b;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ProductName+": "+ProductPrice+"\n";
    }
}
```

and my program is here

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PreLab6 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int NumOfProducts;
        String ProductName ;
        double ProductPrice;

        System.out.println("Enter the number of products:");
        NumOfProducts = scan.nextInt();



        while(NumOfProducts >= 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of product:");
            ProductName = scan.next();


            System.out.println("Enter the price:");
            ProductPrice = scan.nextDouble();

            NumOfProducts--;
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't complete my program because am supposed to use arrays, but no arraylist. I should have output like this:

Enter the number of products: 
2 
Enter the name of product: 
meat 
Enter the price: 
25.30 
Enter the name of product: 
egg 
Enter the price: 
1.20 
meat: 25.3 
egg: 1.2

Comment: Use the `NumOfProducts` (which by the way should be lowercase to start) to make an array of `Products` then add each new product to the array.  I suggest using a `for` loop.

Comment: What's your question? Why couldn't you complete it? What problems did you run into when attempting to implement this using arrays?

Comment: @tnw my questions is that i didn't know how to store the inputs in an array and i didn't know the difference between arrays and arrayList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, i meant to change Products[] to Product[]. The class is a single Product, so it doesn't make sense to be Products

You can initialize an array of size numOfProducts, which then you can loop over and start filling with user input.

Unlike `ArrayLists`, `Arrays` are fixed size (Which are good if you know the amount of items you want to store before hand). `Arrays` come in handy for this type of solution because you know the number of products you are storing before hand using `numOfProducts`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOfProducts;
    String productName;
    double productPrice;

    System.out.println("Enter the number of products:");
    numOfProducts = scan.nextInt();
    //Create an array of Products using the user value stored in numOfProducts
    Product[] products = new Product[numOfProducts];

    //Loop over products, and initialize each space with a new product
    for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of product:");
        productName = scan.next();

        System.out.println("Enter the price:");
        productPrice = scan.nextDouble();

        products[i] = new Product(productName, productPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree doing his homework for him will make him a better programmer

Comment: I agree giving some pointers in the top section, and providing him with a partial solution that still wouldn't be able to compile with copy and paste is a decent step for someone to learn something with.

Comment: 1 for the correct answer. However, it would be better if you can explain OP why you need to initialize the array with `numOfProducts`  unlike Array List. This is where the OP's main confusion was.

Comment: I do like that new explanation though, that seems a lot more informative and helpful so good job.

Comment: Well for One `Product` will be invalid.

Comment: But that was stated in your answer so I figured the OP would be smart enough to read and change that (maybe I have too high of expectations), I was saying "really" at the scanner initialization.

Comment: If they read the answer, i'd assume they would have an understanding of what i did to help them come to a solution. However, most go straight to code, copy/paste and ask why an example doesn't compile. Thanks for pointing out the `System .in` though heh.

Comment: @austinwernli I agree with this for your _newest version_ of the answer.  I don't agree that the first version of the answer was enough.  And you make me sad, I liked the `System. in`.

Comment: thanks for your effort @austinwernli though, but the programe still not working the way it should be

Comment: In which way does it not work? This isn't meant to be a copy/paste entire solution @AhmedYounis

Comment: yea, but i didn't know the difference between array and array list and how to store objects in an array so i tried the program you answered but  couldn't complete it though am new to programming @austinwernli